# ajax doesn't respond - create.js.erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-fileupload-rails

I'm working with jquery-file-upload-rails gem to upload multiple images with preview on my form. File upload is working, but the partial with new photos renders only after browser refresh! Maybe, someone can see, what is wrong.

I'm calling file uploader to load photo images in project's edit page:

```
= f.fields_for :photos, Photo.new do |ff|
  = ff.file_field :img_file, multiple: true, name: "project[photos_attributes][][img_file]", id: 'new_photo'
```

Photo controller:

```
  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @photo = @project.photos.create(params[:photo].permit(:img_file))
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
```

photos.js.coffee to make the jquery-file-uploader-rails gem working:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#new_photo').fileupload
    dataType: 'script'
```

create.js.erb

```
$('#photos').html("<%= j render(@photo) %>");
```

_photo.html.haml

```
.photo
  - @project.photos.each do |photo|
    = image_tag photo.img_file.thumb
    = link_to 'Remove', photo, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete
```

So I can upload photos. But my ajax doesn't work, even if I put only alert('help'); in my create.js.erb, it doesn't respond. What am I doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
**Current situation** (with help of Rich Peck):

My models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  validates :img_file, presence: true
  mount_uploader :img_file, ImageUploader
end
```

Projects controller:

```
  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.photos.build
  end

  def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.update(project_params)
  end

params.require(:project).permit(photos_attributes: [:img_file])
```

/projects/edit

```
  = form_for @project do |f|
    = f.fields_for :photos do |p|
      = p.file_field :img_file, multiple: true, id: 'new_photo'       
  #photos
    = render 'photos/photo'
```

/photos/_photo

```
.photo
  = image_tag photo.img_file.thumb if photo.img_file?
  = link_to 'Remove', photo, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete
```

/photos/create.js.erb

```
$('#photos').html("<%= j render(@photo) %>");
```

/javascripts/photos.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#new_photo').fileupload
    dataType: 'script'
```

Comment: in your form upload add remote: true, this will enable ajax request

Comment: @Marv-C, thanks for your reply! I added it to my form, still not working! Actually I was following this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x23aIQPa-DY, and it worked for one model with ajax rendering, but doesn't work in my case with two models, though I can upload images, just no ajax rendering..

Comment: You don't need `remote: true` for jquery-file-upload; it's handled by the plugin

Comment: @RichPeck you're right. im also trying to debug this problem with no luck at all.

Comment: @RichPeck, is it even possible to render ajax for this plugin with nested forms? Uploading works, rendering not...

Comment: Yes it's possible. But you don't need nested forms

Comment: @RichPeck, thanks for your reply! Then how should I organize my form with file_field? I also updated my post to check my models.

Comment: Posted all relevant code

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('#photos').html(escape_javascript("<%= j render(@photo) %>"));
```

see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript

Comment: Says that an alert won't fire in his `.js.erb` so I doubt a syntax change would do much

Comment: have you tried to debug with Firebug? With the `network` tab, you can see what is being sent to the browser. With the error console, you can detect errors on the browser side.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues.

```
#app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :html

   def new
      @project = Project.new
      @project.photos.build #-> this will replace Photo.new in fields_for
   end

   def create
      @project = Project.new project_params
      @project.save
      respond_with @project
   end

   private

   def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(photos_attributes: [:img_file])
   end
end 

#app/views/projects/new.haml
= form_for @project do |f|
    = f.fields_for :photos do |ff|
       = ff.file_field :img_file, multiple: true, id: 'new_photo'
```

When using nested attributes, you should never be declaring the `name` attribute of your nested fields. Not only is it against convention, but it also leaves the door open to both hacking & bugs.

If you are using `nested attributes`, you need to be passing the `@project` object first, which means the form will either be passing to `projects#update` or `projects#create`... *not* `photos#create` that you have now.

I would also strongly recommend using the [`responders`](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) gem, it will clear up your code massively.

--

If you wanted to create a new `Photo` object on its own, you'll want to use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :projects do
   resources :photos #-> url.com/projects/:project_id/photos/new
end

#app/controllers/photos_controller.rb
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :html

   def new
      @project = Project.find params[:project_id]
      @photo   = @project.photos.new
   end

   def create
      @project = Project.find params[:project_id]
      @photo   = @project.photos.new photo_params
      @photo.save
      respond_with @photo
   end

   private

   def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit(:img_file)
   end
end

#app/views/photos/new.haml
= form_for @photo do |f|
   = f.file_field :img_field
```

---

Your JS code is incorrect...

```
$('#photos').html("<%= j render(@photo) %>");
```

By default, Rails [handles "collections"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) by calling `_[collection_singular_name].html.erb` - in your case `_photo.html.erb`. It loops through the collection to show this each time. To fix yours, just remove the loop from your partial:

```
#app/views/photos/_photo.html.erb
= image_tag photo.img_file.thumb
= link_to 'Remove', photo, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete
```

---

## Solution

Decide whether you're creating a `project` or `photo`.

If you are creating a `photo`, you should use a separate `photos` controller (outlined above). If you're creating a new project, you should use `nested attributes` properly. We've used `JQuery-File-Upload` multiple times before (you can [sign up for free](http://bvc-video.herokuapp.com) its only a test app):

[image]

Your code structure looks okay, only the controller & JS which have issues.

---

**Update**

To add a new photo through a project's `edit` form, just use the following:

```
#app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @project = Project.find params[:id]
      @project.photos.build
   end

   def update
      @project = Project.find params[:id]
      @project.update project_params
   end

   private

   def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(photos_attributes: [:img_file])
   end
end

#app/views/projects/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :photos do |p| %>
      <%= p.file_field :img_file %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! But what if I want to create a **new photo** in project's page (/projects/edit). How should I call this **= form_for @photo** there and render them?

Comment: You'd need a nested form - I can update about this if required

Comment: Could you please update this in order to add new photo from project's edit page? I'm a little confused, to be honest.

Comment: sure, let me do that.

Comment: thank you a lot for helping me. But it still doesn't work. Now my files don't attach and when I submit on form, it says **Missing template projects/update** I updated my post with current situation, please, have a look, maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

For ajax file upload to work in `jquery-file-upload` gem

you have to add  `:html => { :multipart => true}` to your form

`<%= form_for Upload.new, :html => { :multipart => true}  } do |f| %>
...
<%end%>`

Please see the [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example/blob/master/app/views/uploads/index.html.erb)
 example form for reference